# Какие существуют Lorem img API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Подскажите какие-нибудь api изображений, которые возвращают массив ссылок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот например, https://picsum.photos, тут тебе и рандомные картинки и списком вроде тоже можно.

Comment: Ведь смотрел на этот сервис, проглядел https://picsum.photos/v2/list?&limit=3, спасибо